# Significant difference one sample T-test fits with my hypotheses?

Tags: t-test, equivalence

My hypotheses are as following:
Energy intake 
H0= the mean energy intake is between 90-110% of the calculated requirement.
H1= the mean energy intake is not between 90-110% of the calculated requirement.

Because this hypotheses contain a range, the following sub-hypotheses are formed to test if H0 will be rejected: 
H0= the mean energy intake is > 110% of the requirement. 
H1= the mean energy intake is ≤ 110% of the requirement.

H0= the mean energy intake is ≥ 90% of the requirement.
H1= the mean energy intake is < 90% of the requirement.

I want to use the one sample T- test to compare the intake with the requirements but i don't exactly know how. 
For example energy intake: The research population consists of 21 people with a different intake and different requirements. I calculated the mean intake and requirements (for 90% and 110%, so i do 2 t-tests for both values). When doing the one sample T-test to check the significant difference from 90% of the requirement, i choose for energy intake and put the mean requirement for 90% (1911 kcal) in as test value. The result is: t(20)=-3,292, p=0.002, wat means that there is a significant difference and H0 of the sub-hypotheses can be rejected. But, i am wondering if i'm doing this the right way. Do i have to include all 21 people in this t-test, or only the ones who have an intake of less then 90% of the requirement?

Comment: What you are describing is an equivalence test, search this site